# Flash Dynamic TextFiled Font Issue on BOLD

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs3

am using AS3 and i have one dynamic text filed. The properties
 Fontname "verdana" 
 size "14"
 style "Bold"

it is shown the correct font in **BOLD** if there is no value 
if i assign values like

```
 priceText.text=" Hello Wold"
```

It will not show the correct font properties am not getting the bold style :(

What need to change?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c37867425c.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c37867425c.jpg)

Comment: how do you assign your formatting? if you're using embedded fonts, is the font embedded properly?

Comment: Are you creating the text field on the stage or with code? If it's through code could you post the code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the formatting for the TextField you need to set the [defaultTextFormat](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#defaultTextFormat) property. If you don't do this, any new text will default back to the old setting.

Answer (score 0):

am assuming priceText is a dynamic text box already present on stage. you have to change its properties

uncheck the AutoKern box to remove that property
and use the Embed button to Embed the font properties like uppercase,lowercase,punctuation,numerals

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you'll try to make a "TextFormat" instance with the correct properties.. and apply the TextFormat instance on the TextField each time you change the text dynamically (apply it after you change the text).. It will work!

Good Luck!